# How to initialize 2D list of custom class objects - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create a 2D array of objects but getting this error:

```
array required, but List<List<TransitionObject>> found
----
```

This is my TransitionObject Class:

```
public class TransitionObject {
    public char character;
    public int state;

    TransitionObject(char character, int state)
    {
        this.character=character;
        this.state=state;
    }
}
```

and this is my main class code:

```
List<List<TransitionObject>> liist = new ArrayList<List<TransitionObject>>(); 
liist.add(new ArrayList<TransitionObject>());
liist[0].add(new TransitionObject('a',1));
liist[0].add(new TransitionObject('b',3));
```

I am getting this error when I try to add an object to my list. Solution with a short example would be nice. Thanks !

Comment: [0] <- that is array syntax but there are no arrays in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    liist[0].add(new TransitionObject('a',1));
```

is wrong. `liist` is no `array`.

if you need the first element from a `List` use `get()`

```
    liist.get(0).add(new TransitionObject('a',1));
```